# Store data into an array from a for loop from a website cURL

Tags: php, arrays, curl

I am trying to "steal" product names from  a website in order to list it on my own. I wish to store these values in an array. I have currently printed them out successfully via a cURL and stripped all styling.

Here is my code :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.nrs.com/category/3101/whitewater-kayaking/helmets");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

$website = file_get_contents('example_homepage.txt');
//COLLECTED AND STORED WEBSITE AS VARIABLE

preg_match_all('#\<h2>(.+?)\<\/h2>#s', $website, $unfiltered);

$products = array_pop($unfiltered);
$remove_how_much = (count($unfiltered[0]))-(array_search('Follow Us:',$products));


for($count=1;$count<=$remove_how_much;$count++) {
    array_pop($products);
}

for($counter=0;$counter<=(count($products)-1);$counter++) {
    $explode1 = explode('>',$products[$counter]);
    $explode2 = explode ('</a',$explode1[1]);
    echo $explode2[0];
    echo '<br/>';
}

?>
```

Go test this out quickly an you will see it prints it out. I am looking to save these values into an array, check whether there are repeats, and take out the word

```
- Closeout
```

from all values.

I have also fallen into the need of checking other paginated pages,

So, I would need to loop from

```
http://www.nrs.com/category/3101/whitewater-kayaking/helmets?pg=1
```

to

```
http://www.nrs.com/category/3101/whitewater-kayaking/helmets?pg=2
```

and so on until It receives an error or duplicated pages.

Any ideas?

Also, Is there a way to improve my current code to grab it more efficiently.

Comment: What's the problem? Run your code in a loop, incrementing the page number in the URL. When you get an error, break out of the loop.

Comment: I don't know if it would be more efficient, but it would be more correct to use an HTML parser instead of regexp to parse the files.

Comment: Why are you writing the webpage into a file, and then reading the file? Why not just read the webpage directly into the variable?

Comment: You can append `?ppg=all` to show all the items, so you don't need to make tons of http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/simple_html_dom.php/download)

```
<?

include("simple_html_dom.php");

$html = file_get_html('http://www.nrs.com/category/3101/whitewater-kayaking/helmets?ppg=all');


foreach($html->find('h2') as $element)
       echo $element->plaintext."<br />";

/* OUTPUT
WRSI Trident Composite Helmet
WRSI Moment Fullface Helmet With Vents
WRSI Moment Fullface Helmet Without Vents
WRSI Current Pro Helmet
WRSI Current Helmet Without Vents
WRSI Current Helmet Without Vents
WRSI Current Helmet With Vents
WRSI Current Helmet With Vents
WRSI Current Rescue Helmet without Vents
WRSI Current Rescue Helmet with Vents
WRSI Limited Edition Current Helmet
NRS Chaos Helmet - Side Cut - Closeout
...
*/
?>
```

Homepage http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/